# What is homotopy type of the classifying space ${\rm B}\mathcal{C}$ of the groupoid $\mathcal{C}$ with 2 elements?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the groupoid with 2 elements:

$Ob(\mathcal{C}) = \{ a, b \}$,

$Mor(a, b) = \{ f \}$, and

$Mor(b,a) = \{ f^{-1} \}$.

I am interested in the question that what is homotopy type of the classifying space ${\rm B}\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{C}$.

I know that ${\rm B}\mathcal{C}$ is simply-connected.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal C$ is contractible as a groupoid, so $B\mathcal C$ is contractible